# A manga world where no-one dies and heroes & monsters sent their representatives to fight for entertainment

Tags: story-identification, manga

The protagonist (anti-hero?) is a member of a party. He seems weak, but hides great power.

- His teammates diss him a lot. Only the leader is kind and trying to prevent the members from firing him, but did not succeed. So he got outs, and tried to do everything by himself.
- Setting: A world in which no-one dies, everything is for entertainment and hero + monster(?) send a representative to fight in area(?) dungeon(?)
- Have magic, anti-hero kinda feel.
- Manga I read some time ago. Less than 3 years.
- Japanese manga.

I recall the protagonist met someone and he/she disclosed more information about his power.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Do you mean his powder or his power?

Comment: _"Only the leader is kind and trying to prevent the members from firing him, but did not succeed"_ So the MC was expelled from his party?

Comment: yup, trying to go through the check list and adding things, but I am afraid I might add mixed details about other manga I read before though.

Comment: "LogicDictates" Yes he did. And he is not a Jester by the way, it came up during my google search while using "teammate" "representative" "anti-hero" "fight" "entertainment"

Comment: How long ago did you read this? Can you give a time range like 5-10 years ago? Three years ago? Twenty?

Comment: Less than 3 years ago. Recently I lost my phone that has bookmarked from mangadex, trying recoup what I have but mangadex suffer the attack recently, the manga list is not as extensive as before I believe.

Comment: @hell rise - Can you be a little clearer about the _"no one dies"_ part? Is everyone immortal/invincible, or does no one actually try to kill anyone?

Comment: @LogicDictates I mean no one dies from actual battle, not immortal, sorry for the mixed up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is [*Welcome to the Impregnable Demon King Castle ~The Black Mage Who Got Kicked Out of the Hero Party Due to His Unnecessary Debuffs Gets Welcomed by the Top Brass of the Demon King's Army~*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/LightNovel/WelcomeToTheImpregnableDemonKingCastle). (Warning, TvTropes link)

The story is set in a world where Humans and Monsters fight each other with magical clones, so Dungeon Raids have become entertainment like sports. Video feeds are broadcast out making it world wide entertainment. The main character specializes in Dark magic, which in this setting is debuffs. Due to the subtlety of the magic, most of his party wants him kicked out of the party to be replaced with a more damage oriented mage, one that looks flashier. The party leader refuses, understanding the power of his friend, but the main character quits. He was fed up with the comments from the rest of the party.

As mentioned in the title, after he left his friend's party, he joined up with the Demon King which could be where the anti-hero feeling came from.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly it.

Comment: man, this site is so great, so fast and everyone is so civilized in regards to asking about manga.

Comment: @hellrise - btw, not always fast -- we've had some tough story id questions that got answered years later.  So if you ever ask a question we can't answer, check in later and you might be surprised!